# Git is detecting changes in files I did not touch at all?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a small problem, I made some changes in the project I am working it and I commited my changes and pushed it, then I made a merge request to my expert, and in gitlab I see some changes in files I did not touch.

Now I dont now how to solve such problem, I am using SourceTree and I don't know if I can restore the old version of those files.

those files for example, I never knew they exist even in the project, so what solution do I have ?

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It seems the entire file content has been added, in other words, it looks as these files are considered added, not changed.

Comment: These files may be created by your compiler. If you need to ignore these files, then add them to gitignore

Answer (score 0):

Check files changed by doing,

> **$ git status**

Fire a command to revert changes back by following command (for particular file):

> $ **git checkout** ***changed-file-full-name-here***

If there are many files you want to revert then add single space between file names like below (for many files),

> $ **git checkout *file-1-name* *file-2-name***

And enter, all your changed files will be reverted to old code.

Hope it works!